# ImportError: No module named xgboost and package already installed

Tags: python, conda, xgboost

When I do:

```
import xgboost
```

I get no module named xgboost

I tried:
pip install xgboost

and i get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: xgboost in e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from xgboost) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from xgboost) (1.4.1)
```

versions

```
Python 3.7.4
pip 20.0.2 from E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

Where python:

```
E:\Anaconda\python.exe
C:\Users\Federico\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `pip --version` and `python --version`

Comment: And the output of `where python`?

Comment: done, I added versions and where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this will happen because

1. You installed the package in a virtualenv and are trying to import it outside of the env
2. You installed the package globally and are trying to import it in a virtualenv which does not inherit the global packages
3. Your pip is linked to a different version than the python you're using

Based on the output of the `where python` it seems like you probably used the `pip` from anaconda to install the package, but are trying to import the package in a script that you're running with the python located here `C:\Users\Federico\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe` rather than here `E:\Anaconda\python.exe`

If your code with the import is in a script called `test.py`, for example, try running it with `E:\Anaconda\python.exe test.py` and see if the error still occurs

Or start a Python shell with `E:\Anaconda\python.exe` and then execute `import xgboost` in the shell and see if that works

Comment: Ok, I started a Python shell, and it works, problem is I'm using jupyter notebook, how can I solve this, so I can use it inside jupyter notebook?

Comment: @Fede are you using a virtualenv at all?

Comment: i'm using the base conda enviroment

Comment: @Fede According to the [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html), they don't recommend using the base environment. Try creating a new environment like this: `conda create --name dev xgboost jupyterlab` and then activate it with `conda activate dev`. Then you should be able to use it in your jupyter notebook with no issues, as long as the environment is still activated. Does this work?